# -1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'VideoWriter'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pandas as pd



cap = cv2.VideoWriter(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("image", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My code is here. How can fix it?

I want to fix it

```
cap = cv2.VideoWriter(0)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function
```

'VideoWriter'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - VideoWriter() missing required argument 'fourcc' (pos 2)
> - VideoWriter() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)
> - VideoWriter() missing required argument 'fourcc' (pos 2)
> - VideoWriter() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error.

Change this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoWriter(0)
```

to:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```